# Access value of variant object in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have Object of the product please check below. can you please let me know that how can I get the variants value. I have tried to get variant.inventory_quantity but can not get

```
{
    "id": 9129131982,
    "title": "Universal Suction Base Adapter",
    "handle": "usb-universal-suction-base-adapter",
    "description": "\u003cp\u003eAll F-Machines are supplied with a Vac-u-Lock style adapter as standard, which are compatible with Doc Johnson Vac-u-Lock dildos and toys.\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eF-Machine brings you the brand new Universal Suction Base (USB). This revolutionary bolt on system integrates your favourite suction (\/flared) base sex toys with either your F-Machine Pro II or Gigolo. With this fantastic innovation from the pervy engineers at F-Machine, you can now choose which style of toy to use on your machine and discover new possibilities for sexual play \u0026amp; fantasy.\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cul\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eDesigned to fit all F-Machine 10 mm thrust rods\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eInjection moulded from shatter proof plastic composite material\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eOver-moulded brass threaded insert for maximum durability and holding capacity\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eOption of dildo retention via suction, O-rings or Velcro straps (or combination)\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eFits dildos with suction base diameter up to 88 mm (when installed)\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eSupplied with a comprehensive O-ring set and range of Velcro straps to fit most dildo sizes\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eCan be used with Double Trouble\u003c\/li\u003e\n\u003c\/ul\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cstrong\u003ePlease note:\u003c\/strong\u003e F-Machine fucking machine and toys are not included (for illustration purposes only).\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e \u003c\/p\u003e",
    "published_at": "2016-11-25T16:29:00-11:00",
    "created_at": "2016-11-25T16:36:50-11:00",
    "vendor": "F-Machine",
    "type": "",
    "tags": [],
    "price": 4900,
    "price_min": 4900,
    "price_max": 4900,
    "available": true,
    "price_varies": false,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "compare_at_price_min": 0,
    "compare_at_price_max": 0,
    "compare_at_price_varies": false,
    "variants": [{
        "id": 31980207054,
        "title": "Default Title",
        "option1": "Default Title",
        "option2": null,
        "option3": null,
        "sku": "",
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "taxable": true,
        "featured_image": null,
        "available": true,
        "name": "Universal Suction Base Adapter",
        "public_title": null,
        "options": ["Default Title"],
        "price": 4900,
        "weight": 600,
        "compare_at_price": null,
        "inventory_quantity": 2,
        "inventory_management": "shopify",
        "inventory_policy": "deny",
        "barcode": ""
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

inventory_quantity was [deprecated](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product_variant) recently. Instead, you'll have to use:

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/inventorylevel